# how many objects are eligible for garbage collection when end line of main is reached?

Tags: java

My main problem is how many object is really created at executing the line

```
Dozens [] da = new Dozens[3];
```

And how many object will be eligible for garbage collection at the end of main function

```
class Dozens {
  int[] dz = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
}

public class Eggs {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dozens [] da = new Dozens[3];
    da[0] = new Dozens();
    Dozens d = new Dozens();
    da[1] = d;
    d = null;
    da[1] = null;
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you come up with? Why do you want to know?

Comment: I got a doubtful answer in SCJP book they give total five objects are created. But i think 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After executing `Dozens [] da = new Dozens[3];` a single object will be created. After the `main` method is finished, if you don't create another thread that uses the objects created in `main`, all the objects that you created will be available for garbage collecting.

```
public class Eggs {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dozens [] da = new Dozens[3]; //one array object created
    da[0] = new Dozens(); // one Dozens object created
    Dozens d = new Dozens(); //one Dozens object created
    da[1] = d; 
    d = null; //nothing available for gc here, as there is still a referrence to that Dozens object (da[1])
    da[1] = null; //da[1] available for gc
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i come out that total 3 objects will be created including da (array object) and all will be elligible for GC.

Comment: I think you missed the dreation of the Dozens.class-Object. As far as I know, there will be a instance per class created.

Comment: The array inside Dozens will be garbage collected when Dozens object is garbage collected.

Comment: I got a doubtful answer in SCJP book they give total five objects are created. But i think 3

Comment: If you count the arrays inside Dozens, then there are five objects.

Comment: @sayemsiam SCJP is right: 5 objects are created: da array, 2 dozens objects + 2 int[] arrays within the dozens objects

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there isnt an intervening GC, the three instances of Dozens that were created will all be eligible.

There's no boxing of the primitive arrays.

Comment: and the arrays are Objects too ;)

Comment: There are only 2 instances of Dozens.

Comment: Dozens [] da = new Dozens[3]; this line should create only one object

Answer (score 0):

2 instances but what were u thinking with that :O

```
da[1] = d; //points 
d = null; //attended. 
da[1] = null; //already null.
```

Answer (score 0):

class Dozens contains an int array object. Therefore every time you create a Dozens object two objects are created (one instance of Dozens, which again contains one instance of an int array).

```
    class Dozens{
  int[] dz = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};}
  public class Eggs {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Dozens [] da = new Dozens[3]; //one object capable of holding 3 instance 
        da[0] = new Dozens();   //2 object 
        Dozens d = new Dozens(); //2 object 
        da[1] = d;            //no new object d,da[1] point to same d object
        d = null;         //one object for gc
        da[1] null;       //one object for gc
        //do stuff
    }
  }
}
```